# Create auto update trigger for single field update postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I have a table named `vehicle`  like this

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle
(
    id                  varchar,
    status              TEXT,
    created_at          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
   
);
```

I want to create a trigger which will on trigger only when the `status` value is modified.

till now have  a trigger which work on whole table fields and it is written like this

**first function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_timestamp()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$function$
BEGIN
    NEW.status_updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
;
```

**then trigger**

```
create trigger update_timestamp
    before update
    on vehicle
    for each row
execute procedure update_timestamp();
```

reference for this trigger is  this  https://x-team.com/blog/automatic-timestamps-with-postgresql/

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  both cases . status change in any combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change your trigger to execute trigger function only when status has changed:

```
create trigger update_timestamp
    before update
    on vehicle
    for each row
    when (OLD.status IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.status)
execute procedure update_timestamp();
```